# How to run Spring Cloud Config server in Fault Tolerance mode?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices

In my project we have a requirement to run two instances of spring cloud config server so if one instance goes down, other will take care the config server responsibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you would need to put config server behind a load balancer. It is stateless, so that wouldn't hurt. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/342) to configure multiple config server url's in the client, so it could do failover there.

Comment: What if I register multiple config server instances to my Eureka server? Wouldn't that automatically load balance my config server instances?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running multiple instances of the config server, you can have them all register themselves in Eureka, and maybe do a lookup to the config server with it's application name via Eureka in all the other microservices. This way, Zuul (and Ribbon) will take care of the load balancing.

**Edit:**
I guess spencergibb is right. It's best to use a load balancer, for eg: ELB, if you're going to deploy on AWS.

[Consider multiple spring-cloud-config-uris for high availability](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/87)

Comment: In this scenario can we have our eureka properties in our config server?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but we'll have to use discovery-first bootstrap in this case, which means that the config server will register in Eureka. But for this our Discovery service will have to be at a fixed point.